# Emphasize 100% axis line in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a bar chart of %s, where some of the values are over 100%. I have the gridlines set at 20%, but would like an extra emphasis on 100% to make the better values stand up.

Comment: More details would be helpful, or a picture of what you have and a picture of what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial shows a few ways to indicate a target on your bar chart: [Add a Target Line to an Excel Chart](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/add-a-target-line/)